# Running C++ code asynchronously in a C# program

Tags: c#, c++, asynchronous, task, language-interoperability

I wrote some backend code in C++ and I wrote a frontend for it in C#. What I want it to do is run the backend code in the background so I can do other things like update a progress bar, but when I click the "Start" button, the program hangs until it's finished running the backend code.

C# code:

```
    [DllImport("backend.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int executeBackend();

    private async void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        startButton.Enabled = false;
        await StartProgram();
    }

    private async Task StartProgram()
    {
        int status = 0;
        status = executeBackend(); //This is causing the UI to deadlock
        startButton.Enabled = true;
    }
```

backend.dll C++ code:

```
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) int executeBackend()
    {
        int statusCode = 0;
        //Do stuff in the background
        return statusCode;
    }
}
```

If I comment out the call to run executeBackend and replace it with `await Task.Delay(5000);`, the UI doesn't deadlock. How would I fix this?

Comment: ExecuteBackend is blocking and not returning.  An Asyn method must return while it is running in background.

Comment: Also. don't ignore compiler warnings. The `StartProgram` method will cause a compiler warning that literally says it will run synchronously (i.e., block the calling thread).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the call to `executeBackend` in a `Task` to prevent the UI from locking up.

```
var status = await Task.Run(() => executeBacked());
```

I also think you're confused about what the `async` keyword actually does. I think it might be prudent for you to read up on how [Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) works in dotnet.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! And yes I'll read up! This was my first time trying to do asynchronous programming.

Answer (score 2):

**You need to rethink how your C++ code handles asynchronicity.**

You should be able to pass the C++ side a callback function, so that you can hand off the whole operation and return a `Task`.

Something like this (note the `StartProgram` function is using `TaskCompletionSource` and is *not* marked `async`.)

```cs
[DllImport("backend.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void executeBackend(BackendCallback func);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void BackendCallback(int result);

private Task<int> StartProgram()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    BackendCallback callback = result =>
    {
        tcs.SetResult(result);
        GC.KeepAlive(callback);  // prevent GC from disposing unmanaged callback
    };
    executeBackend(callback);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

I'm not familiar enough with C++ to show you that side.

But essentially you need to be able to take a parameter of type  `void (*) (int)` function pointer, hand off the operation to another thread, and then on completion you call back the C# side using the function pointer.